# Processing 3.0 ketai camera. Image cannot be saved

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-camera, processing

Hello I am using **processing 3.0** with **ketai library** and I am trying to save an image but for some reason it does not work. Each button has its own listener in order to identify if it was pressed. The camera opens normally but when Save button is pressed nothing happens. an error message is displayed in the processing console. The message that is displayed in the console is:

> failed to create directory to save photo: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/**testing6**

**testing6** is the .pde file that I am working on. Also, I am testing the application on a android emulator and not on an android device. I want to be able to save an image and create a folder that contains images. For instance, one folder will have animal photos, other folder will have landscape, etc. Create any number of folders and photos. I saw the documentation on Ketai library and on GitHub but I could not find a solution.

```
import ketai.camera.*; 
import java.lang.String.*;  
KetaiCamera camera;



void setup()  
{
    camera = new KetaiCamera(this,width,height/2,15); 
    // 0: back camera; 1: front camera 
    camera.setCameraID(0); 
}  

void draw()  
{  
     image(camera, width/2, height/2, width, height);  
     drawUI();
}  

void drawUI()  
{  
     fill(255);
     stroke(0);
     orientation(LANDSCAPE);
     //here there is a for loop to create the buttons when the camera open
     //there are many buttons in other pages that is why we start from 28.
     for(int i = 28; i <= 31; i++)        
     {
         buttons[i].draw(color(0,128),textColor);
     }
} 

void onCameraPreviewEvent()  
{  
    camera.read(); 
} 

void onSavePhotoEvent(String filename)  
{  
    camera.addToMediaLibrary(filename);  
}  

//mousePressed is a build-in function and I check which button was pressed.
//each button has on click listener.
void mousePressed()  
{  
    if(buttons[28].isPressed())          //button Start, PAGE CAMERA 
    {
        if (camera.isStarted())
        {
            camera.stop();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!camera.start())
            {
                println("Failed to start camera.");
            }
        }
    }//end of if statement for the START button

    else if(buttons[29].isPressed())        //button Save, PAGE CAMERA
    {
        if(camera.isStarted())
        {
            camera.savePhoto("test.png");
        }
    }//end of else if for the SAVE button

    else if(buttons[30].isPressed())        //button Flash, PAGE CAMERA
    {
        if (camera.isFlashEnabled())
        {
            camera.disableFlash();
        }
        else
        {
            camera.enableFlash();
        }
    }//end of else if statement for the Flash button

    else if(buttons[31].isPressed())      //button Exit, PAGE CAMERA
    {
        camera.stop();
    }//end of else if statement for the Exit button

}//end of mousePressed function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of Android ask the user for permission to access sensitive resources at runtime, not during installation. So you need to prompt the user to give your app permission to write to the file system, *before* you invoke `KetaiCamera::savePhoto()`.

From the [Processing for Android documentation](https://android.processing.org/reference/permissions/request.html):

```
void setup() {
  requestPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "checkPermission");
}

void checkPermission(boolean wasPermissionGranted){
    if (wasPermissionGranted)
        println("Hooray! I can now write to the local file system!");
    else 
        println("Oh no! I was not granted write permission =(");
}
```